# How to properly use type hints in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, casting, type-hinting

I can't figure out how to properly use type hints in my type_casting function.

```
def type_casting(var, _type):
    if _type not in (str, int, float, bool):
        return Exception

    return _type(var)

assert type_casting("55", int) == 55
assert type_casting(55, str) == "55"
```

How to properly use type hints in Python?

I want to do something like this:

```
T = int | float | str | bool
def type_casting(var: Any, _type: Type[T]) -> T:
```

Comment: Not sure the `|` operator distributes over `Type[...]`, might be more sane to do `Type[int] | Type[float], ...`

Comment: Yes, this is not a working option. I just wrote approximately what I would like to receive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Any` and `TypeVar`

```
from typing import TypeVar, Type, Any

T = TypeVar('T', int, float, str, bool)

def type_casting(var: Any, _type: Type[T]) -> T:
    if _type not in (str, int, float, bool):
        raise ValueError(f"Unsupported type {_type}")

    return _type(var)
```

You can reference here [TypeVar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html?highlight=typevar#typing.TypeVar)

Comment: This is much more elegant than my solution !

Answer (score 1):

This seems a bit cumbersome, but you can get it to work with some overloads. Note that you have to start with the narrower type, otherwise it could never be reached and MyPy complains about it.

```py
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING, Any, overload

T = int | float | str | bool


@overload
def type_casting(var: Any, type_: type[bool]) -> bool:
    ...


@overload
def type_casting(var: Any, type_: type[int]) -> int:
    ...


@overload
def type_casting(var: Any, type_: type[float]) -> float:
    ...


@overload
def type_casting(var: Any, type_: type[str]) -> str:
    ...


def type_casting(var: Any, type_: type[T]) -> T:
    if type_ not in (str, int, float, bool):
        raise Exception

    return type_(var)


my_int = type_casting(55, int)
my_float = type_casting(55, float)
my_str = type_casting(55, str)
my_bool = type_casting(55, bool)

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    reveal_type(my_int)  # note: Revealed type is "builtins.int"
    reveal_type(my_float)  # note: Revealed type is "builtins.float"
    reveal_type(my_str)  # note: Revealed type is "builtins.str"
    reveal_type(my_bool)  # note: Revealed type is "builtins.bool"

assert type_casting("55", int) == 55
assert type_casting(55, str) == "55"
```